# handle InvalidTypeIdException with jackson

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

Here is Base class annotated with JsonType and JsonSubTypes with mandatory "type" field required.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes(value = {
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubA.class, name = "A"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubB.class, name = "B")
})
public abstract class Base {
    private String type;

    public String getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

There is below class which wraps above class and is used in controller. This wrapper class is taking "type" already which need to be passed to class Base above

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class BaseWrapper {
    @NotBlank
    private String type;
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private Base base;

}
```

Finally , validation are here in controller

```
@PostMapping("/createBase")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> createBase(@RequestBody @Valid BaseWrapper)
{    
    ...
}
```

Sample JSON that works with controller validations in spring boot -

```
{
  "type":"A",
  "base": {
     "type:"A",
     //fields of A
  }
}
```

How can the duplicate type be removed from inside base itself like below. this gives `InvalidIdException` from Jackson.

```
{
  "type":"A",
  "base": {
     //fields of A
  }
}
```

I understand using Custom Deserializer is one way but  then JsonTypeInfo, JsonSubTypeInfo and all validations being done by default does not apply and everything has to be hand-crafted.

Can the type required twice be fixed so that only outer Json type is propagated to inner and Jackson understands it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY` but note from javadoc:

> Inclusion mechanism similar to PROPERTY, except that property is
>   included one-level higher in hierarchy, i.e. as sibling property at
>   same level as JSON Object to type. Note that this choice can only be
>   used for properties, not for types (classes). Trying to use it for
>   classes will result in inclusion strategy of basic PROPERTY instead.

So this will not work on class level but on property in wrapper

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Getter
@Setter
public static class BaseWrapper {
    @NotBlank
    private String type;

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)
    @JsonSubTypes(value = {
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubA.class, name = "A"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubB.class, name = "B")
    })
    private Base base;

}
```